# Display dialog when menu option, or string in watched file changes?

Tags: macos, script, user-interface, applescript

I'm running a program where I have a shortcut bound in OS X (Sierra 10.12.3) to toggle a menu option. However, there is no visibility in the app of the status of that menu option without navigating to it in the menu to see if it is checked, thereby defeating the usefulness of the shortcut.

How can I make an app that would run as a process at login, and remain running, and each time a specific string in the .plist for the program I'm running changes, it would output to a dialog pop-up reporting the status of the menu option, which would automatically close in one second?

For example purposes, consider the following as the defined variables:

- plist file: /Users/foo/Library/Preferences/com.bar.plist
- string to watch for: menuItemChecked
- string present in file: output "menu item checked!" to display popu
- string is removed from file: output "menu item unchecked!" to display popup

Or...

If there is some easier way (using an Applescript or other means) to visibly display some UI feedback of the status of a menu option being checked or unchecked, I'm open to that as well.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!!!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What has your research led you to believe?

Comment: I haven't the foggiest idea how to make this work. The closest I could get was a script to watch the preferences folder for changes, but that is regularly updated, so not a lot of help.